# Ajax - 500 Internal Server Error on LocalHost

Tags: django, ajax

I am trying to create an EditForm for my data in Django and am receiving a 500 Internal Server error whenever I hit Save Changes. Screenshots below are of the process within Console and when I click on the xhr error. Any idea what would be causing this, considering I am just on my local http://127.0.0.1:7000 server at this point?

views

```
class UpdateCrudUser(View):
    def  get(self, request):
        id1 = request.GET.get('id', None)
        employee1 = request.GET.get('employee', None)
        description1 = request.GET.get('description', None)
        stakeholder_group1 = request.GET.get('stakeholder_group', None)
        stakeholder_quadrant1 = request.GET.get('stakeholder_quadrant', None)

        obj = Stakeholder.objects.get(id=id1)
        obj.employee = employee1
        obj.description = description1
        obj.stakeholder_group = stakeholder_group1
        obj.stakeholder_quadrant = stakeholder_quadrant1
        obj.save()

        user = {'id':obj.id,'employee':obj.employee,'description':obj.description,'stakeholder_group':obj.stakeholder_group,'stakeholder_quadrant':obj.stakeholder_quadrant}
        data = {
            'user': user
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

urls

```
    path('ajax/crud/update/',  views.UpdateCrudUser.as_view(), name='crud_ajax_update'),
```

html

```
        // Update
        $("form#updateUser").submit(function() {
            console.log("open");
            var idInput = $('input[name="formId"]').val().trim();
            var employeeInput = $('input[name="formemployee"]').val().trim();
            var descriptionInput = $('input[name="formdescription"]').val().trim();
            var stakeholder_groupInput = $('input[name="formstakeholder_group"]').val().trim();
            var stakeholder_quadrantInput = $('input[name="formstakeholder_quadrant"]').val().trim();
            console.log("create");
            if (employeeInput && descriptionInput && stakeholder_groupInput && stakeholder_quadrantInput) {
                // Create Ajax Call
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{% url "polls:crud_ajax_update" %}',
                    data: {
                        'id': idInput,
                        'employee': employeeInput,
                        'description': descriptionInput,
                        'stakeholder_group': stakeholder_groupInput,
                        'stakeholder_quandrant': stakeholder_quadrantInput
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.user) {
                          updateToUserTabel(data.user);
                        }
                    }
                });

            console.log("submitted");
            }
            else {
                alert("All fields must have a valid value.");
            }
            $('form#updateUser').trigger("reset");
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            return false;
        });

        function updateToUserTabel(user){
            $("#userTable #user-" + user.id).children(".userData").each(function() {
                var attr = $(this).attr("employee");
                if (attr == "employee") {
                  $(this).text(user.employee);
                } else if (attr == "description") {
                  $(this).text(user.description);
                } else if (attr == "stakeholder_group") {
                  $(this).text(user.stakeholder_group);
                } else if (attr == "stakeholder_quadrant") {
                  $(this).text(user.stakeholder_quadrant);
                }
              });
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Check the command line console for the full error message. Copy it and paste it in your question.

Comment: Sorry, how would I find the error message within my command line console?